# How to use a function element inside another function

Tags: python, function, oop

I have this issue where i want to print the result widget.text inside another function ,any idea?

main.py:

```
class FloatLayoutExample(Screen):
    text_input_str = StringProperty("foo")

    def on_text_validate(self, widget):

        self.text_input_str = widget.text
        return widget.text


    def call_gui(self):
        print(self.text_input_str)
```

Comment: Your code already seems to fit your requirements. Is there some problem with it?

Comment: Are you getting trouble passing the result from your function into a variable and then passing the variable into another function to print the `widget.text`?

Comment: I apologise i forgot to mention the desired objective , in call_gui function i want to print widget.text as follow : def call_gui(self):
        print(widget.text)

Comment: Ok, but what’s wrong with the current code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code , i just need to pass widget.text to call_gui function that's all

Comment: `self.text_input_str` already stores `widget.text` as seen in your code so what you're printing should already be that if you called `on_text_validate`.

Comment: Indeed it does but when i print self.text_input_str it gives 'foo' as an output from text_input_str = StringProperty("foo") ,but my objective is to print the stored widget.text because it has another value coming from the used when inserted ,i just want to know if there is anyway how i can print specifically widget.text in call_gui function .

Comment: You can store it as a different class variable and call it in your function.

Comment: can you give me a hint please ?

Comment: Make a class variable `widgetText` and in your `_init_` pass in `widget.text` and set `widgetText` to `widget.text`.